# Can Entity Framework be used to generate SQL Server Compact database

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-ce

I created a project as described [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc835495%28SQL.100%29.aspx) using Visual Studio 2010 and .NET 4 (Win7/x64). Once I've change the platform target to 'Any CPU' the sample project works. However, if try to generate a model from entity data model (right-click the model and select 'Generate Database from Model'), I get the following error.

*Could not find the appropriate DbProviderManifest to generate the SSDL. The supplied provider invariant name 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5' is not valid.*

I have a reference to System.Data.SqlServerCe on my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I appear to have just fixed

> Error 175: The specified store provider cannot be found in the configuration, or is not valid.

when opening the `.emdx` eitehr as XML or in the designer.

I needed to add the element

```
<add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider"
     invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5"
     description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact"
     type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"/>
```

To my `machine.config` as a second entry under `<configuration><system.data><DbProviderFactories>` (alongside a similar one for SQL Compact V4).

This made it match another system where I wasn't getting error 175.

*NB.* Adding this to `app.config` wasn't sufficient for the designer (searching the web indicates this is needed at runtime if the CE 3.5 tools have not been installed).

Comment: Don't have a chance to test this now, but I'll take your word for it. Marked your answed as accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**An update to @Richard 's answer:**

In the case of using  *SQL Server Compact Edition v4.0*, you should have the following lines in your machine.config file:

```
<system.data>
  <DbProviderFactories>
  <add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider 4.0"
       invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" 
       description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact"
       type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"/>
  </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed...

Here's an equivalent for 3.5

    <system.data>
        <DbProviderFactories>
   <remove invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5" />
   <add
    name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider"
    invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5"
    description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact"
    type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory,
      System.Data.SqlServerCe,
      Version=3.5.0.0,
      Culture=neutral,
      PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"
   />  
  </DbProviderFactories>

    </system.data>

Answer (score 0):

It should work, but there are some extra steps that you need to take. See: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stevelasker/archive/2008/10/22/privately-deploying-sql-server-compact-with-the-ado-net-entity-provider.aspx

Comment: I downloaded the sample project from the link you provided and upgraded it to VS2010. I had to update the DLL links in the AMD64 and X86 folders. Now I get the following compiler error.

Comment: Error 175: The specified store provider cannot be found in the configuration, or is not valid. File: LocalData.edmx

Comment: try opening up your edmx file add see if there is any error messages. The problem may be related to the structure of your database

Comment: If you mean opening the edmx in VS model designer, then no, I don't get any errors.

Comment: No open it in notepad and have a look at the xml

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. The edmx is an XML file. What exactly am looking for? Is it valid XML? Yes! If I open the XML in VS XML editor, it show the same error 175.

Comment: @Rubio: See my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674302/can-entity-framework-be-used-to-generate-sql-server-compact-database/6453336#6453336) on how I resolved Error 175.